# Large margin off the page

Tags: html, css

I have an image that I want to achieve a certain effect.  Essentially as you make your browser window smaller, I want to crop off left and right side equally, so that the image is not resized and I always see the center.

I have accomplished that in the following way:

```
<style>
    .banner{
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 350px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .banner img{
        position: relative;
        left: 300%;
        margin-left: -600%;
    }
</style>

<div class="banner"><img src="https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/0B1qZWmK2ucS8ZDN3Ni02VXo2SEE=w1129-h720-iv1" alt="Image is missing" /></div>
```

Js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/szsj6f9m/

One thing I have noticed with this approach is that if I make left be 100% and margin-left be -200% the image will then half way through start sliding back to the right.  I don't fully understand why, I just know that I need to make the percentage to 300% so it behaves correctly on 320px screen.

Here is the example of what I am talking about, just resize your browser small to big and you will see what I am talking about:

Js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/szsj6f9m/1/

**My question is this:**

Is it ok to have the position of the screen so far and throw such a large left-margin on it?  Does this causes any kind of problems from the performance point of view on smaller devices or any devices really?  Are there any reasons you can think that would say not to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use `left:50%;transform:translate(-50%,0);` (works even for vertical centering) `top:50%;transform:translate(0,-50%);` https://jsfiddle.net/szsj6f9m/3/

Comment: That would be supported for IE9 and up, I believe my version is for browser even earlier than that.  However, that is also a nice approach thanks for that.

Comment: @Bagzli to be honest... Don't bother with archaic browsers... It's way to depth of hell for both devs and clients. :\ - When someone access websites of bigger projects i have worked on, i just trigger an overlay popup, with the background correctly rendered as screen shot (blurred) and force visitors to upgrade their browser for the sake of everyone.

Comment: I have a redirect on, but I'm writing this code for somebody else and I want them to have their options open and make that decision themselves.

Comment: @Bagzli that is reasonable, but i'd advise them not to bother with it... The share of older browsers is dropping rapidly in last years (and that is for the best) nowadays it's something around 1-2% tops
As a valid argument - try to tell your client to visit the official websites of Microsoft. (Even on freshly installed SP1 Win7 IE, it looks like broken s*** TBH)